# Problem accessing variable declared in one file in extension file

Tags: ios, swift, global-variables

I  declared a variable in my ViewController.swift file like this:

```
struct serials{
    static var snToConnectTo2 = ""
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
....
}
```

I want to access this variable from my KeyboardViewController.swift file which belongs to an extension of my application that ViewController.swift controls.

I am trying to access the variable like this:

```
serials.snToConnectTo2
```

When I try to compile my code I get the following error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'serials';
```

How do you properly access variables from different files?

Comment: Are you sure you define your struct **outside** of the viewController ? or nested inside?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I edited the post to show how I have defined my struct. I have defined it outside of my ViewController class.

Comment: Seems Ok to me. I can't reproduce the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you need to declare your struct as public and its properties like the following:

```
 public struct serials{
 public static var snToConnectTo2 = ""

 public init() {

 }
}
```

second you need to link this file (I mean the file that contain your struct) as described in the following screenshot

[image]

then choose your file and add it, and it will work fine with you

Answer (score 0):

it's not giving any error

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Sclass: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("run1: \(serials.snToConnectTo2)")
        serials.snToConnectTo2 = "abc"
        print("run2: \(serials.snToConnectTo2)")

    }
}


struct serials{
static var snToConnectTo2 = ""
}
```

output is

```
run1: 
run2: abc
```

---

If you are still facing any error ... please provide

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
....
}
```

---

Comment: The struct is not being used in the same file. I am trying to access it from a different file.